# How to use specific fonts, Verdana for example with libharu in Ubuntu

Tags: c, linux, libharu

I have some type1 types in /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/, and even more after installing msttcorefonts. But in that diversity of fonts, i dont know which one is verdana or arial or else. And no verdana entries was found in /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/fonts.dir.

Here my code to load font:

```
font_name = HPDF_LoadType1FontFromFile (pdf, "/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/a010013l.afm",
  "/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/a010013l.pfb");
```

EDITED:
Looks like using next function call resolves issue:

```
font_name = HPDF_LoadTTFontFromFile (pdf,
  "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType/Verdana.ttf", 
  HPDF_TRUE);
```

Comment: msttcorefonts are TTF, not Type1.

Comment: Great thanks, you pointed me to right direction))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

msttcorefonts are TTF, not Type1.